# Solving $\sin\left(2x\right)+5\bigl(\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(x\right)\bigr)+1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification

I attempted to do this trig problem I have written below with steps I took to reach an answer. Did I do this correctly?
$$\sin\left(2x\right)+5\bigl(\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(x\right)\bigr)+1=0$$

using the well known identity: $\sin^2\left(x\right)+\cos^2\left(x\right)=1$, I get:

$$\color{red}{\sin\left(2x\right)}+5\bigl(\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(x\right)\bigr)+\color{red}{\sin^2\left(x\right)+\cos^2\left(x\right)}=0$$

Then I see that the "red" is just $\bigl(\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(x\right)\bigr)^2$, so
$$\bigl(\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(x\right)\bigr)^2+5\bigl(\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(x\right)\bigr)=0$$

Then I let $u=\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(x\right)$, I get
$$u^2+5u=0$$
$$u=0,\:\text{and}\:u=-5$$

removing $u=-5$ as no solution, leaving just $u=0$ as the only solution, plugging back into the defined "$u$",

$$0=\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(x\right)$$
$$\sin\left(x\right)=-\cos\left(x\right)$$
$$\tan\left(x\right)=-1$$

the solution I get is
$$x=\frac{3\pi }{4}+\pi n$$

No need to see if there are any extraneous solutions since the function is continuous.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: You're correct :)

Comment: So, how many of these trig equations are you going to ask about? When will you get some confidence in your ability to solve them?

Comment: Yes, this solution looks good

Comment: @Gerry Myerson just wanted to see if I did them correctly. I am notorious for solving trig equations wrong.

Comment: Your last step is better handled with $0=\sin(x)+\cos(x) = \sqrt{2} \sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$.

Comment: @Neat Math Can you explain how you got that?

Comment: Just expand the RHS.

Answer (score 3):

Overall, looks great, though I've a few things to comment on.

---

My first criticism is that you should perhaps justify the following:

- $(\sin x + \cos x)^2 = \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x + \sin 2x$. This is easily done by squaring the binomial by noting $\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x$.
- $u = -5$ generates no solution. This follows easily since $\sin x, \cos x$ are, at minimum, $-1$ each.

Granted, as noted, these are simple justifications (clearly you already know them), but perhaps would be appreciated by your instructor for completeness (if this is for a class).

---

Next, towards the end, you divide by $\cos x$ in order to get $\tan x$. This results in a problem if $\cos x = 0$, though. Thus, you need to handle that case separately, and need to determine whether or not $x$ can be such that both sine and cosine are equal to zero.

(Obviously, they're not, and you have the complete solution set -- this is just, again, in the interest of completeness.)

Comment: Thanks! this isn't for a class (at least not currently) They used to be though. (that's a bit confusing isnt it? :) I'm just doing them just for practice and also I wasn't able to solve any of them during that time (in class).